# PDO Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in... file

Tags: php, pdo

I know this have been asked several times but I didn't find the one that matches my situation, so, had to ask.

I have two files
1) connection.php

```
class Database {

    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
        $user = 'dbuser';
        $pass = 'dbpass';

        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function displayInfo() {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fname, lname FROM info");
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

}

$db = new Database();
```

2.) info.php

```
require_once 'connection.php';

$result = $db->displayInfo();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['fname']. " " . $row['lname'];
}
```

I understand I cannot use the `fetch()` with `$result` and if it was in same page I could use `$stmt->fetch()` but couldn't figure out how to call this `PDO fetch` from another page.

Comment: I know you are not here to explain the downvote of genuine question. Anyways, thank you for taking your busy time to come here and sniff around with your big-time-charlie ego. you sir need a big hi5 in the cheek !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PDOStatement::execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method returns true on success or false on failure -- not the result of the query. You need to return your statement instead:

```
public function displayInfo() {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fname, lname FROM info");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

In this way the `$result` variable is actually your statement and you can call the `fetch()` method on it.

A better way is to do the fetch from inside the `displayInfo()` method and return just the results and not have to rely on bringing your Database goodies outside of the class like:

```
class Database 
{

   protected $dbh;

   public function __construct() {
      $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
      $user = 'dbuser';
      $pass = 'dbpass';

      try {
         $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
   }

   public function getDisplayInfo() {
      $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fname, lname FROM info");
      if( $stmt->execute() ) {
         return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
      // Query failed
      return false;
   }
}

$db = new Database();

$results = $db->getDisplayInfo();

foreach($results as $row) {
   echo $row['fname']. " " . $row['lname'];
}
```

Comment: I guess I have done the same here `return $stmt->execute();` and have stored the value in `$result` from where I was calling. BTW, how to proceed with your second method, I am quiet new to PDO

Comment: @your common sense was correct, instead of using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` the `fetchAll()` did the trick. I have edited your answer to meet that.

Comment: I edited the answer but some peer didn't like it. Anyways what I edited was changed this line `return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to `return $stmt->fetchAll();` and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

The proper code. See details in [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
class Database {

    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
        $user = 'dbuser';
        $pass = 'dbpass';
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);
    }

    public function displayInfo() {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fname, lname FROM info");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: The real proper code would disable emulated prepared statements when connecting with mysql and probably set the encoding of the connection. And just use `PDO::query()` when there is nothing to prepare.

Comment: I am upvoting this because I mixed this `return $stmt->fetchAll();`  with @Cillious answer, which was suitable for me. Thank you !!!